# is it possible to put more than one CSS rule in a lesscss forloop?

Tags: css, for-loop, less

Is it possible to put the following in a lessCSS forloop so that just the number of each section variable will update from section1 through to section4 with each loop?

// loop starts

```
.section1 {
    .color {
         color: @section1;
    }
    .colorBG-medium{
         background-color: @section1;
    }
    .colorBG, .tab.active a {
         background-color: @section1;
         &:hover{
             background-color: @section1;
         }
    }
}
```

// loop ends

thanks!

Comment: According to [this site](http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/), it's possible, I think. But as I don't actually use Less I can't verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [link](http://blog.thehippo.de/2012/04/programming/do-a-loop-with-less-css/) indicated by [Roddy of the Frozen Peas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419705/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), yes it is possible to do a loop, but it only makes sense to use it for numeric values​​. For your case, I recommend using the [mixins](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins), including to improve code readability:

```
#foo {
    .bar (@color) {
        .color { color: @color; }
        .colorBG-medium {
            background-color: @color;
        }
        .colorBG, .tab.active a {
            background-color: @color;
            &:hover{
                background-color: @color;
            }
        }
    }
}

.section1 {
  #foo > .bar(red);
}

.section2 {
  #foo > .bar(blue);
}
```

The result:

```
.section1 .color {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.section1 .colorBG-medium {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.section1 .colorBG,
.section1 .tab.active a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.section1 .colorBG:hover,
.section1 .tab.active a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
.section2 .color {
  color: #0000ff;
}
.section2 .colorBG-medium {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.section2 .colorBG,
.section2 .tab.active a {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
.section2 .colorBG:hover,
.section2 .tab.active a:hover {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A probably better way to achieve that result would make use of a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins). Something like:

```
.section-color (@color) {
    .color {
         color: @color;
    }
    .colorBG-medium{
         background-color: @color;
    }
    .colorBG, .tab.active a {
         background-color: @color;
         &:hover{
             background-color: @color;
         }
    }
}

.section1 {
    .section-color(red);
}
.section2 {
    .section-color(#123456);
}
/* ... */
```